# How many creatures can you heal with Balm of Peace?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, healing

Tasha's Cauldron of Everything introduces the Peace Domain for the Cleric; which at level 2 gains the **Balm of Peace** Channel Divinity option

> You can use your Channel Divinity to make your very presence a
> soothing balm. As an action, you can move up to your speed, without
> provoking opportunity attacks, and when you move within 5 feet of any
> other creature during this action, you can restore a number of hit
> points to that creature equal to 2d6 + your Wisdom modifier (minimum
> of 1 hit point). A creature can receive this healing only once
> whenever you take this action.

How many creatures can this heal within the movement? If I move through the entire party can I heal them all? Or does this only refer to a single creature?

It reads to me that I can heal as many as I can reach with my movement, especially given the last line, but the *any other creature*, and *that creature* lines give me pause for thought.

Comment: By "target" you mean "restore hit points to", right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### As many as you can reach with your speed.

The Peace Cleric's [Channel Divinity: Balm of Peace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#PeaceDomain) says:

> As an action, you can move up to your speed, without provoking opportunity attacks, and *when you move within 5 feet of any other creature during this action*

Providing the healing has two conditions that must be met:

- you move within 5 feet of another creature
- it is during this action

So *any* time during the action that you move within 5 feet of another creature, you can provide the healing (limited to once per creature per use of the feature). Notably, *this movement does not use your usual movement for the turn*. So if your speed is 30 feet, you can move 30 feet during this action and heal your allies, and you still get your usual 30 feet of movement. Think of it is a Dash action with some healing.

Comment: Assuming of course that it is a different creature. You can't move 5 feet away and then back to heal that creature again. So not technically "any time" but close enough. Right?

Comment: @TheGrandJ  Well, yeah, but that part is unambiguous and not what was asked about, so I didn’t mention it.